# SQL query for detect columns with special characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

here and in a lot of other websites I have find a lot of posts regarding this question but for some strange reason no one works.

I have a Wordpress database and I need to find all the terms contained in wp_terms that have any special character.

In fact I need to find all that contains anything else of number or letter.

Why this doesn't work? The MySQL query return 0 results.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **REGEXP** to find out this. Also the ^must be outside from [].

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name REGEXP '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]'
```

**Test**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT "Hello" REGEXP '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]' as resut;
+-------+
| resut |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT "-Hello" REGEXP '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]' as resut;
+-------+
| resut |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just try this in phpMyAdmin but the query return me all the terms without a special charachter. I'm looking to get all the rows that contain a special charachter.

Comment: sorry, change it to this **'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]'**

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because MySQL supports the ANSI version of `LIKE`.  The form that you are using is an extended form associated with SQL Server.

On the other hand, MySQL supports regular expressions which are much more powerful.  The regular expression for what you want is:

```
WHERE name REGEXP '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]'
```

Note that regular expressions match the pattern *anywhere* in the string, so you do not need wildcards at the beginning and the end.